# Can pulsating DC be used for induction heating?

Tags: dc, inductance

I want to make an induction heater work using a 12 v, 35 A-h battery(used in cars). I don't want to use an inverter. Will a pulsating DC input to the induction heater make it work?

Comment: How is generating high-power, high-frequency DC pulses any easier than building "an inverter"? The only difference is a DC-blocking device such as a transformer or a capacitor.

Comment: How fast are you able to switch the DC input? You probably need to reach the kHz range for it to be useful.

Comment: If it's "pulsating", it's not DC.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: "DC" stands for "direct current", and is defined to be current that flows in a single direction, regardless of its magnitude, as opposed to "AC", or alternating current, that flows in two directions. "Pulsating DC" is a perfectly valid concept.

Comment: The constraint is that I have to use a 12 v, 35 A-h battery to generate heat(without an inverter). Aren't there any DC input heating devices?

Comment: That is different. Resistance wire or power resisters can be used instead if all you need is heating. Is Induction a requirement or just what you thought might be needed?

Comment: Olin is right.  If it's pulsating, then you necessarily have AC.  Even if there's enough DC offset to never cross zero, the pulsating part is still, and entirely, AC.  Now that we have that, we can plug it into the standard equations and go from there.

Comment: Also, don't forget to account for the local heating and saturating effect of the DC component.  It does nothing for induction, but it does heat the wire/bar/whatever that it runs through and tends to magnetically saturate any sort of ferrous material that might be around.  Saturation is basically the magnetic equivalent of clipping, and usually causes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your "pulsating DC" is likely to be a square wave. OR, even if your DC were pulsing between two non-zero values.  The answer is yes.

Applying any changing voltage (current) to your induction coil at any frequency can and will likely result in induction heating of a conductor inside of your induction coil. You don't even need a resonating capacitor to achieve induction heating.

Things get a little more complicated when you try to make a Good induction heater. Your 12v source sounds good for a very small induction heater. For first step, search around on internet (i.e. youtube), for other amateurs who are doing similar things. Selecting a frequency (or repetition rate) and resonating capacitors is of course essential to obtaining higher efficiency so that your limited power source could actually demonstrate Visible heating.

Answer (score 1):

Dependig on your needs this may help
http://www.rmcybernetics.com/projects/DIY_Devices/diy-induction-heater.htm

http://www.rmcybernetics.com/shop/cyber-circuits/pulse-generators/induction-heater-circuit

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here too: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Answer (score 1):

If I may add... pulsating current is on/off on/off where alternating current is forward/backward forward/backward. A pulse width modulator (PWM) with an appropriately sized DC solid state relay may or may not work.