# Induction heating circuit also stable with forward or reversed DC current through work coil?

Tags: power-electronics

I have need for an induction heating coil (high frequency and current AC) that can also switched to a steady forward or reversed DC current in order to create a stable magnetic field in the work coil - is there any way of achieving this without giving up on soft switching?

How inefficient would it be to drive an induction heating work coil with a full bridge (as used for dc motors) under logic control instead of using an oscillating circuit? In addition to the extra switching losses from using hard instead of soft switching and the far noisier emissions from the square wave instead of sinusoidal what other bads are there?

*Edit:
While I have looked at the question and answers for [Can pulsating DC be used for induction heating?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153321/can-pulsating-dc-be-used-for-induction-heating) despite giving me assurance that it is possible it doesn't help me with how to design an efficient circuit for my use case.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can pulsating DC be used for induction heating?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153321/can-pulsating-dc-be-used-for-induction-heating)

Comment: Are you wanting the DC and high frequency applied simultaneously?

Comment: No the DC and HF are at separate times: The coil will have four states - oscillating, DC, inverted DC, unpowered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All high powered commercial induction heaters use an [H bridge](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/H-bridge).

Use a [series LC resonant tank circuit](https://www.printfriendly.com/p/g/nSZ7Dp). Which you would model as a series RLC (includes resistance of the load).

Drive the series load at a frequency just ABOVE resonance. This reduces OFF switching to near zero. ON switching losses are also near zero.

Remember to use anti-parallel diodes on each switching device.

Get a circuit simulator to observe that switch OFF losses reduce as you approach resonant frequency.

You want to run slightly above resonance to allow the diodes to forward bias just after switching off. By doing so, the voltage across the NEXT switching device will be near zero during turn ON.

Keep in mind that the coil voltage (and capacitor voltage) will be higher than the output voltage of the H bridge.  Coil volts will be Q times the output voltage of the H bridge. (Q of the coil).

EDIT 1 :  For parallel tank, the H bridge needs to be designed as a current source, (as opposed to a voltage source used with series tuned circuit).

You don't just apply a square wave to a parallel tank. An inductor is used in series with the output of the H bridge to create a pseudo current source. And control circuit is more complicated.

In series LC circuit the voltage applied (H bridge) is square wave and current is sinusoidal at resonance. Current is triangular above resonance and slowly morphs to sinusoidal as frequency is lowered to near resonance.

Comment: Anything with a series LC tank prevents me applying a stable DC required at other times. Amy chance you could rework your answer with advice for running a parallel LC tank circuit (this would allow me to simply stop switching with the relevant high/low sides connected)

Comment: What power level and frequency do you need for the heating? It is very common in commercial heating to use a parallel tank. For parallel tank, the H bridge needs to be designed as a current source, as opposed to a voltage source used with series tuned circuit.  You don't just apply a square wave to a parallel tank. An inductor is used in series with the output of the H bridge to create a pseudo current source. And control circuit is more complicated.

Comment: Looking to push around 400 watts around the coil - was thinking I could charge the parallel tank, disable both high and low sides on H-bridge and let the tank ring for a cycle or two then detect zero crossing and reconfigure the H-bridge in order to top off the tank

Comment: Frequencies maybe in the 20-40kHz range

Answer (score 0):

Induction heating would not create for you a stable magnetic field because its based on a switching suarewave source. Your best bet a stabilized DC current feeding a high resistance coil or solenoid coil which will yield a very stable field as long as the fed DC current is stable.